# How do I implement nested routing in react properly

Tags: reactjs, routes, nested

I'm going crazy here since two days. Guys please help. I'm trying to implement nested routing. But its not working. When I go to http://localhost:3000 it displays correctly. But when I go to http://localhost:3000/contact.  It doesn't work. I've tried all I can.  Please help

```
//App js
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './features/Main/Main';
import Dashboard from './features/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Nomatch from './features/Nomatch';

function App() {

    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/'> <Redirect to='/home' /></Route>
                <Route path="/home" component={Main} />
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route component={Nomatch} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );

}

export default App;
```

/////////////////////////////////////////

```
//Main.js
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Contact from './Contact';

const Main = () => {
const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
    return(
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path={`${path}/contact`} component={Contact} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Main
```

Comment: I don't want to have /home/contact. But /home , /contact /faq  /dashboard.  Is it possible

Comment: You need to wrap the children of `Main` with a router

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You could try changing in *Main*:

```
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path={`${path}/contact`} component={Contact} />
            </Switch>
```

by

```
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/home'><Redirect to='/' /></Route>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
            </Switch>
```

And in *App*

```
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={Main} />
            </Switch>
```

Comment: I don't want to have /home/contact. But /home , /contact /faq /dashboard. Is it possible – user3118363 42 secs ago    Edit   Delete

Comment: Then you could try to redirect in the Main app instead, I will update the answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a bunch.  It worked.  And I also decided to use an alphabet 'm' instead of 'home'. I appreciate you